# PostgreSQL: Order by one representation, but show another

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregation

new to SQL in general, I have this date column, I want to group by day of week and order the result by it, but I want the resulting relation to show the day of week as the name ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', etc).

To order by day of week, I need an integer representation, but to show the name of the day, I need the character name.  Both can be extracted from the date column that I have

integer form for ordering:  `extract(dow from date)`

character form for presenting: `to_char(sa.sale_date, 'Day')`

The problem is in combining both in the same query - since it's an aggregation, the non-aggregated names in my select statement must be exactly those names in my group by, so if I want to show the char form, I need to group by the char form. However, the integer form is then not in my table, so I can't order by it. I can't order by a function of the date directly since the date is not in my aggregated table either.
I can of course group by both the char form and the int form and include them both in my table, but in the interest of learning - I wonder if SQL allows an alternative, since this problem can be quite general.

In the general case:
How can I order by one reductive representation of a column, but present another reductive representation of that column (assuming those reductive representations have a 1-to-1 mapping between them) - ***without having the form by which I order appear in the result***?

Minimal example:

table 'Sales' holds columns: 'sale_date', 'product_name', 'quantity', 'store_id'

I want a the result to have columns 'store_id', 'day_of_week', 'total quantity'
Here total quantity is the sum of 'quantity' for each store_id and day of week.
I want the result to be ordered by store_id and day_of_week, where day_of_week is in char form (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc) but they are ordered according to their integer value (in order of days in the week, not by their names in alphabetical order).

Comment: please se [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) #5 and #3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bit tricky, but easy to solve. For your group use the minimum or maximum date, which is one of the Mondays for the Monday group , one of the Tuesdays for the Tuesday group, etc.

```
select to_char(min(sale_date), 'Day') as sale_day, count(*)
from sales
group by extract(dow from sale_date)
order by extract(dow from sale_date);
```

Or do it the other way round. Group by day name and order by the minimum or maximum date of the group.

```
select to_char(sale_date, 'Day') as sale_day, count(*)
from sales
group by to_char(sale_date, 'Day')
order by extract(dow from min(sale_date));
```

Another option (that I don't like as much): Group redundantly by both expressions.

```
select to_char(sale_date, 'Day') as sale_day, count(*)
from sales
group by to_char(sale_date, 'Day'), extract(day from sale_date) 
order by extract(dow from sale_date);
```

Comment: Ahh I see, so you aggregate on the day too, allowing you to use it. or in the second, you order by an aggregation, I didn't know that was possible. Very helpful, thank you!!